# Curl Upload: Give file does not exist

Tags: curl, ftp, upload

I am trying to upload a file using curl but it says:

> curl: (19) Given file does not exist

This error message is not related to the source file it's related to the destination. I know this because when i create an empty file on the server using FileZilla and then uploading it it works perfectly fine.

The command i am using:

```
curl -I --http1.0 -T "cache.txt" "ftp://user:passwd@fastdownload.nitrado.net/unturned/hash.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path of `cache.txt`, i.e.:

```
curl -I --http1.0 -T "/full/path/to/cache.txt" "ftp://user:passwd@fastdownload.nitrado.net/unturned/hash.php"
```

---

Also make sure you've the appropriate permissions on `unturned` dir.

Comment: And yeah the permissions are no problem, I am using the same account to upload files in filezilla.